# Embedding a login page form on 3rd party website with CSRF risks?

Tags: php, csrf, csrf-protection, exploit

We currently have a login form to gain access a new platform we are working on.

Form is generic Username / Email + Password

We added in a CSRF key to prevent forgeries, clients are asking if they can embed the login form directly on their websites now. How can we do this on a separate domain whilst still preventing CSRF?

This would effectively allow the same form on a 3rd party domain which would submit directly to the login script at our end.

Comment: Simple: iframe, more robust: api, so 3rd party site can request CSRF from your site, then send it as a form field, not a cookie

Comment: Thanks @Steve are there any potential pitfalls with just using an iframe? for example if we use javascript for validation of forms etc would this be an issue to execute this on 3rd party domain?